# HBase program not able to connect to ZooKeeper on localhost

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am new to HBase and I am sure i installed it correctly. On my terminal, I am able to start hbase shell also but even a simple create statement gives me the following error : 
(Note : I am trying to run it on stand alone mode)

```
WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode     (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:193)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:450)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ClusterId.java:61)
........
```

Also, I have written only 2 lines in eclipse and I try to run it,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MasterNotRunningException, ZooKeeperConnectionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);
}
```

it gives me the following error :

```
15/03/18 22:25:37 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1/fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
15/03/18 22:25:38 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

What could possible be the issue?
I have my /etc/hosts file as 127.0.0.1 localhost.
Anything else that I need to do or change?

Comment: Without including your configuration files for both zookeeper and hbase, it's going to be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart Here is very good documentation to setup hbase. you might be missing some configurations.

Comment: Did everything that the tutorial said. I think it is some problem with the zookeeper.

Comment: can you share configuration? it would be easier to dig the problem

Comment: any news on this one? I have the same problem here.